# How to get the Previous View Projection Matrix?

Tags: glsl, glsles

I'm working on porting the Motion Blur example from ([NVIDIA's GPU Gems chapters](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-iv-image-effects/chapter-27-motion-blur-post-processing-effect)) to GLSL (ES).

How can one get hold of the 'previous view projection matrix' from inside your Vertex program?